# Extract Image Files in a zip file

Tags: android

I want to extract only image files inside a zip file. Any examples about this? How do I do this?

Solved this problem already.

Added a missing statement `getInputStream()`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485668/591801) for how to unzip a file.  You could alter it by adding a filter on the ze.getName() to filter using a list of image extensions you are looking for.

Comment: I'm unzipping it using only the emulator, after unzipping, the file sizes are all 0 bytes. What happened?

Comment: Where are you unzipping to?  Was there any kind of exception?

Comment: Unzipped it to folder I created, there's no exception. The files are all 0 bytes, is this because I run it in emulator?

Comment: I've never used the emulator.  I guess it's possible, but I find it highly unlikely.  You could add logging to the function to ensure that each file is being found, check the filesize of the file `ze.getSize()` to ensure it's not zero and make sure that the part that's reading the zip file actually reads some data.