# Is there any way to generate a .apk file in external sdcard from my android mobile by clicking on one button?

Tags: android, apk

I have a .apk file of a library project, now i want to use that .apk file in my application project(in assets folder) and while running my application project i want to put a .sql file into that .apk file and when i click on one button then i want to store that .apk in external sd card along with that .sql file. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

apk is compressed format,so may be you can check how to pack and unpack data from apk.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply..Can you please send me some related links for pack and unpack data from .apk ? @ lftikar Urrhman Khan

Comment: take a look at java.util.zip may be this can help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485114/how-to-zip-and-unzip-the-files)

Comment: By using this link i tried for zipping a folder, i got a zip file but when i open it nothing in that it showing error like "The archive is either in unknown format or damaged"

Answer (score 0):

I got by using bellow code:

```
private void onGenButtonClickListener() {
    Button generatebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_apk);

    generatebutton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            generateAPK();

        }

    });
}

private void generateAPK() {
    try {
        String generatedApkPath = GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY + apkname + ".apk";

        String signedApkPath = GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY + apkname + "-signed.apk";
        Log.i("Sign APK", "Going to create signed apk in:" + signedApkPath);

        ZipSigner zipSigner = null;
        zipSigner = new ZipSigner();

        zipSigner.setKeymode("testkey");

        zipSigner.signZip(generatedApkPath, signedApkPath);

        // After signing apk , delete unsigned apk
        new File(generatedApkPath).delete();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "'" + apkname + "-signed.apk' is generated at " + GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Signing apk", "Error while signing apk to external directory", t);
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```