# Extracting a Zip file in App's Internal Storage - Android?

Tags: java, android, storage, unzip

I do not want the overhead of copying so many files from android `assets` directory to my *app's internal storage*. That is why I have created a `zip` file in `assets` folder and I will copy that `zip` file on my *android app's internal storage.* After copying it, I will **extract/unzip** it on the same location and after extraction is complete I will delete this `zip` file.

**The idea is to remove the overhead of copying so many files.** Also while copying so many files I am getting `IOException` with some file types. Which again was a hinderance. That is why I am trying to do so as I have discussed above. ***But the problem is that how can I extract a zip file that is residing in my app's internal storage. I want to extract it on the same location(App's internal storage). How can I achieve this?***

Any help or code is appreciated..!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485114/how-to-zip-and-unzip-the-files. check this if it helps

Comment: Seems like a bad idea. Why are you saving things as a zip, in the end your app might take twice as much space than needed.

Comment: Actually I will delete this zip after extracting it. And I do not want the user to download unzipped large data to android device.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks. Let me check it if it works.

Comment: Check accepted answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324103/download-and-extract-zip-file-in-android

Comment: I have already gone through that question.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a zip file using this code from this [source](http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.ch/2013/08/unzipping-files-with-android.html) :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

import android.util.Log;

public class UnzipUtil
{
    private String zipFile;
    private String location;

    public UnzipUtil(String zipFile, String location)
    {
        this.zipFile = zipFile;
        this.location = location;

        dirChecker("");
    }

    public void unzip()
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                if(ze.isDirectory())
                {
                    dirChecker(ze.getName());
                }
                else
                {
                    FileOutputStream fout = 
                        new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = zin.read(buffer)) != -1)
                    {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    fout.close();

                    zin.closeEntry();

                }

            }
            zin.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
        }

    }

    private void dirChecker(String dir)
    {
        File f = new File(location + dir);
        if(!f.isDirectory())
        {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Give **Write External Storage** permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I am already using this code.