# Android download and encrypt image

Tags: android, encryption, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I am a noob to android, I am trying to download and save images as encrypted form. Here is the image download method in my custom adapter.

I am bit confused how to save the images as the encrypted form ? after downloading and saving need to encrypt that ?

My Image download code looks like

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
      String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
      client.get(imgUrl, new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes) {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
              // Do something with the file
              ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData);
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
              String tag = (String)holder.image.getTag();
              if(imgUrl.matches(tag)){
               holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              }
          }
      });
```

Please give me a little help to encrypt image

Comment: what kind of encryption?

Comment: prevent users view the images directly, prevent from gallery view etc

Comment: rename the file with another extension. *.XXX So it can't be accessed directly by gallery applications.

Comment: tried that. but it can be accessible via "file Manager" app and when open with gallery application, we can see that image. Thats  why encrypting

Comment: create a zip archive of the image with no compression.

Comment: can u please show a small example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485114/how-to-zip-and-unzip-the-files

Comment: Either do not save the images in the first place, or save them to internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`).

Comment: It [http://facebook.github.io/conceal/](http://facebook.github.io/conceal/) can be interesting for your prupouses.